# Is "that" a conjunction or relative pronoun in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunctions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> It comes as no surprise that Taiwan has the highest density of convenience stores in the world.

Is "that" a conjunction or relative pronoun in this sentence?

Comment: What do you think and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**that** in your sentence is a *subordinator*, which introduces the **declarative content clause** *Taiwan has the highest density of convenience stores in the world.*

Some would say it's a *complementizer*, which introduces the complement clause *Taiwan has the highest density of convenience stores in the world.*

A *relative pronoun*, by definition, must refer back to an *antecedent*: in this case, *surprise* is not the *antecedent* of **that**.